# elasticsearch & java - InvocationTargetException and NoNodeAvailableException

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, spring-boot

I am trying to index an object to elasticsearch, but I am having no luck besides finding a lot of dead-ends...

My Application class looks like this:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder;

import org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import static org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory.*;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private FilRepo repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9200));

//      repository.deleteAll();
        List<Fil> listFiler = new ArrayList();
        // save a couple of customers
//      repository.save(new Fil("Steffen-1", 5, new Date(), new Date()));
//      repository.save(new Fil("Steffen-2", 10, new Date(), new Date()));

        // fetch all customers
        System.out.println("Filer funder med findAll():");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");

        for (Fil f : repository.findAll()) {
            listFiler.add(f);
            IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("elasticsearch", "fil")
                    .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                            .startObject()
                            .field("fil", f.filNavn)
                            .field("size", f.filStr)
                            .field("created", f.created)
                            .field("modified", f.modified)
                            .endObject()
                    )
                    .get();





                    System.out.println("RESPONSE ER HER: " + response.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(listFiler);
        System.out.println();

        // fetch an individual customer
        System.out.println("Customer found with findByFilNavn('Steffen-1'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println(repository.findByFilNavn("Steffen-1"));

        client.close();

    }
}
```

My elasticsearch is running which I have checked by going to localhost:9200 it looks like this:

```
name    "WpUHj5-"
cluster_name    "elasticsearch"
cluster_uuid    "nEgvRKklRveOr1ltZSPbeA"
version 
number  "5.5.0"
build_hash  "260387d"
build_date  "2017-06-30T23:16:05.735Z"
build_snapshot  false
lucene_version  "6.6.0"
tagline "You Know, for Search"
```

The error log I get from the mvn spring-boot:run is:
[image]

[image]

and the error on my Elasticsearch window:
which basically says "an existing connection was closed by an external host"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would be good to separate the configuration part from the business logic. So the configuration bean for elasticsearch should be following (note that the [correct port for communication via `TransportClient`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_talking_to_elasticsearch.html) is **9300**, port 9200 is for REST, I think this is the main problem here but maybe not the only one):

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchConfig {

    private static final Logger LOG = getLogger(ElasticsearchConfig.class); 

    private Client client;

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    @Bean
    public Client getClient() throws UnknownHostException {

        Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
                .build();

        client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

        LOG.info("--ElasticSearch--");
        Map<String, String> asMap = client.settings().getAsMap();
        asMap.forEach((k, v) -> LOG.info(k + " = " + v));
        LOG.info("--ElasticSearch--");

        return client;      
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void closeClient() {
        client.close();
    }

}
```

After initializing `client` object, for test purposes, you can check your logic (here the settings of client are printed) but it would be much much cleaner if you could move you logic to a separate service and work with `client` after injecting it with:

```
@Autowired
private Client client;
```

Main Spring Boot class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "pl.jma.es.demo.esrepository")
public class EsDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EsDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```