# spring-data-elasticsearch java.net.SocketTimeoutException timeout exception

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, java-19

Java: 19

Springboot: 3.0

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

### Configuration

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.ClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.support.HttpHeaders;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

@Configuration
public class ElasticRestClientConfig extends ElasticsearchConfiguration {

  @Override
  public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.add("Accept", "application/json");
    httpHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json");

    return ClientConfiguration.builder().connectedTo("search-*****.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com:9200")
      .usingSsl()
      .withPathPrefix("app")
      .withDefaultHeaders(httpHeaders)
      .withBasicAuth("", "")
      .withHeaders(() -> {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("currentTime", LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
        return headers;
      })
      .withBasicAuth("", "")
      .build();
  }
```

When I am triggering request it is throwing exception

```
 java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 5,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-0
```

Comment: you are trying to connect to port 9200 using https? Sure that this is correct?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I was using 443 and it was not not working, so tried with 9300 and 9200 with reference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/45561662

Comment: @P.J.Meisch the exact error for port 443 is co.elastic.clients.transport.TransportException: [es/search] Failed to decode error response

Comment: so is your endpoint then secured with https at all? Or do you need some special authentication mechanism?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch it has https only.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to it was creating own open search/elastic client using Springbook reactive web client.

```
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

  public OpenSearchClient(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
    this.openSearchClient = WebClient.builder()
      .baseUrl("BASE_URL")
      .defaultCookie("cookieKey", "cookieValue")
      .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
      .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
      .defaultUriVariables(Collections.singletonMap("url", "BASE_URL"))
      .build();
  }
```

Without using spring-data-elastic-search.

Comment: You mean for each repository operation, you send an http request instead?

Comment: @PatPanda yes for each type of operation I created different methods, so that request parameters will change and it will do what I want to do. I only need 4/5 types of operation for this, so it is working fine for me and it is very simple now. I will try using spring-data-elastic-search on a dummy project and if it works, later I can use that in other services, for current requirements this will do the job for me.